# PHP - Undefined variable and other errors

Tags: php, undefined, deprecated

Today I wanted to write a simple php script, but I got some annoying errors. 
I just simply include the config.php file and try to access the root_path variable without success. There are also 2 other warnings that only show when I include the config.php file.

The files are running on the newest xampp.

smarty_setup.php :

```
<?php
require('config.php');
require($root_path . '/libs/Smarty.class.php');

class FileHosting extends Smarty {

   function __construct()
   {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->setTemplateDir($root_path . '/templates/');
        $this->setCompileDir($root_path . '/templates_c/');
        $this->setConfigDir($root_path . '/configs/');
        $this->setCacheDir($root_path . '/cache/');
        $this->caching = Smarty::CACHING_LIFETIME_CURRENT;
        $this->assign('app_name', 'File Hosting');
   }
}
?>
```

config.php :

```
<?php
    $root_path = 'D:/xampp/htdocs/example';
    $db_user = 'xxx';
    $db_password = 'xxx';
    $db_name = 'xxx';
    $db_host = 'xxx';
    $facebook_appID = 'xxx';
    $facebook_secret = 'xxx';
?>
```

Errors :

```
Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in D:\xampp\php\PEAR\Config.php on line 80

Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in D:\xampp\php\PEAR\Config.php on line 166

Notice: Undefined variable: root_path in D:\xampp\htdocs\example\includes\smarty_setup.php on line 3

Notice: Undefined variable: root_path in D:\xampp\htdocs\example\includes\smarty_setup.php on line 11

Notice: Undefined variable: root_path in D:\xampp\htdocs\example\includes\smarty_setup.php on line 12

Notice: Undefined variable: root_path in D:\xampp\htdocs\example\includes\smarty_setup.php on line 13

Notice: Undefined variable: root_path in D:\xampp\htdocs\example\includes\smarty_setup.php on line 14
```

Thanks for helping me.

Comment: And what is your question? Are the messages not clear?

Comment: The messages are clear. I simply dont understand why i cant access the variables / why they dont exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your class, you are accessing `$root_path`, which is at the global scope. Pass it into the constructor:

```
class FileHosting extends Smarty {

   // Pass $root_path as a param to the constructor
   function __construct($root_path)
   {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->setTemplateDir($root_path . '/templates/');
        $this->setCompileDir($root_path . '/templates_c/');
        $this->setConfigDir($root_path . '/configs/');
        $this->setCacheDir($root_path . '/cache/');
        $this->caching = Smarty::CACHING_LIFETIME_CURRENT;
        $this->assign('app_name', 'File Hosting');
   }
}

// Instantiate as
$smarty = new FileHosting($root_path);
```

The first of these errors is puzzling, as it would indicate that `config.php` was not properly included.

```
Notice: Undefined variable: root_path in D:\xampp\htdocs\example\includes\smarty_setup.php on line 3
```

If those are indeed the only contents of `config.php` (and you have not set those variables inside a function for example), you ought not get that first `root_path` notice.

#### Update

If you are failing to include `config.php` with a relative path, make sure:

1. `config.php` is in the same directory as the file you are attempting to include it from
2. Check your PHP `include_path` to be sure it includes the current directory `.`:

.

```
echo get_include_path();
```

Comment: Okay thanks. Isn't there a other way? Because i need the path for the Smarty.class.php include.

Comment: @user1384731 The weird thing is you should already have it for the include.  As long as `config.php` was in fact `require()` 'd and correctly parsed, `$root_path` is set and can be used to include smarty.

Comment: Yes, this is realy weird. Using root_path now only for including the second file and there are the same erros. Tried it also with include etc. Double-Checked everything.. but cant find any error.
XAMPP is freshly installed, only enabled curl and set a password for root.

Comment: Ok, i tried now to include the config.php with a absolute path (what is kinda stupid, because i need that path from config.php) and everything worked without any errors. Any idea?

Comment: @user1384731 Check your include path as I have added above.

Answer (score 0):

Try making $root_path a constant instead of a variable:

`define('ROOT_PATH', 'D:/xampp/htdocs/example');`

and then use it like:

`$this->setTemplateDir(ROOT_PATH . '/templates/');`

Comment: Then there's a problem with including files. What errors did you get this time?

Comment: This are the erros when i try it with a constant:
Notice: Use of undefined constant ROOT_PATH - assumed 'ROOT_PATH' in D:\xampp\htdocs\hosting\includes\smarty_setup.php on line 3

Warning: require(ROOT_PATH/libs/Smarty.class.php) [function.require]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in D:\xampp\htdocs\hosting\includes\smarty_setup.php on line 3

Comment: Definitely inclusion problems - test if all the necessary files get included and you'll solve all the issues.